# Why does the address of libc.so always change

Tags: c, assembly, elf, dynamic-linking, aslr

I have recently been looking into ELF binaries and how functions are called using GOT and PLT in an ELF file.

When a function is called this is what occurs as far as i know:

1. function is called
2. a jump is a made to PLT specifically the functions plt stub (`function@plt`)
3. inside `function@plt` a jump is made to GOT to check if the functions address is present, if not it is loaded into GOT
4. next time the function is called the PLT stub (`function@plt`) will jump directly to the function address via the GOT

This makes sense but when doing further research into this i wondered how and why libraries that contain functions are loaded randomly. Specifically here is an example with a ELF dynamically linked binary called `x`:

```
user1@ubuntu:~$ ldd x
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeff6f6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd65aa52000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd65ac94000)

user1@ubuntu:~$ ldd x
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdda5ee000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10242a0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10244e2000)
```

Calling `lld` on the executable reveals that my executable uses `libc.so` where many C standard library functions are located like `printf` for example. However you may also notice that the address changes on each call from `0x00007ffeff6f6000` to `0x00007ffdda5ee000` and upon calling `lld x` multiple times the address always changes.

**Why does the address keep changing and how does the computer know where the new address of libc will be?**

Comment: Security. Read about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). The loader of course knows the address so it sets up the addresses in the GOT accordingly. You can disable it by `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` (for experimenting only). Then the address will not change. Also `gdb` has a setting `disable-randomization`

Comment: @Jester why not make this an answer so that we could +1 it?

Comment: *how does the computer know where the new address of libc will be?* - from the `mmap` return value!  Use `strace /bin/true` to see the system calls ld.so makes for dynamic executable makes to map libc.